# Comparing Two models shared data types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Heello, Im trying to compare two shared data type values from 2 models:

Goals -

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate  { get; set; }
    public  DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Level { get; set; }
    public bool Achieved { get; set; }
```

and 
    Distances:

```
 public class Distance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double DistanceRun { get; set; }
    public DateTime _Date { get; set; }
    public String AdditionalComments { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code to compare which distances were achieved between two dates(goals).

```
public ActionResult AchievedGoals(string type)
    {
        var goals = db.Goals.Where(x => x.EndDate != null).AsEnumerable();
        List<Distance> distances = new List<Distance>();
        foreach (var goal in goals)
        {
            var goalsBetween = db.Distances.Where(x => x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.StartDate) > 0 & x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.EndDate) < 0);
            Distance d = (Distance) goalsBetween;
            distances.Add(d);
        }

        return View(distances.ToList());
    }
```

I am getting an error on the

```
   Distance d = (Distance) goalsBetween;
```

line saying this error

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[WAD_Tracker.Models.Distance]' to type 'WAD_Tracker.Models.Distance'.'

here is the view also:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WAD_Tracker.Models.Goals>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Level)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Achieved)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Achieved)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: you are trying to cast collection of distance to distance. you can try to use db.Distances.where(yourcondition).FirstOrDefault() to get one row of distance

Answer (score 0):

The expression    `db.Distances.Where(x => x._yourWhereClause)` will return a collection(specifically`IQueryable`) of `Distance` object. But in the next line you are trying to cast it to a single `Distance` object,

```
 Distance d = (Distance) goalsBetween;
```

Hence you are getting the error ! You cannot cast a collection to single object.

You do not need to cast to single object. You should call the `ToList()` method on the IQueryable collection which will give you a List of Distance objects andy use the `AddRange` method to add that list to the `distances` list.

```
var distanceList= db.Distances
                    .Where(yourWhereClausePredicate)
                   .ToList();
distances.AddRanges(distanceList);
```

To compare the `Date` value of a a `DateTime` property in the LINQ query, you should use the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method.

```
var distanceList= db.Distances
                    .Where(f => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f._Date) 
                                         <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(goal.EndDate)
                                &&  DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f._Date) 
                                         >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(goal.StartDate)
                          )
                   .ToList();
distances.AddRanges(distanceList);
```

Keep in mind that, calling the `ToList()` inside each iteration of the loop will execute the LINQ query (making a call to the db) to get the result. If your loop size is big, i would advise reading everything to a local cache and querying against that. Again, measure the performance and use the best suiting for your situation.

Comment: using this method gets me this error:

    System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Comment: i took out the extra .Date in the statement and got a new error:


   System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Comment: You cannot use `Date` property to compare inside a linq query. See the updated answer for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem : you can't cast a `DbQuery` to a `Distance`. 
You're currently trying to cast a "prepared query" directly into an object. You can't do that. You need "execute" the query. Try using this line instead

```
var goalsBetween = db.Distances.Where(x => x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.StartDate) > 0 & x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.EndDate) < 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your code seems to be adding multiple distances into a list. To you this you should "execute" your query with `.ToList()` or `.ToEnumerable()` instead as follow

var goalsBetween = db.Distances.Where(x => x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.StartDate) > 0 & x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.EndDate) < 0).ToList().Select(g => (Distance)g);

the `select` call at the end will simply cast each item in the list to a `Distance`.

Then you can add them to `distances` using `addRange" as follow:

```
var goalsBetween = db.Distances.Where(x => x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.StartDate) > 0 & x._Date.Date.CompareTo(goal.EndDate) < 0).ToList().Select(g => (Distance)g);
distances.AddRange(goalsBetween);
```